# Reverse pre-last element of array

Tags: c#, arrays, string, reverse

I couldn't found any better way to do it but to split the string into the array:

```
string str = "unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book";
string[] split = str.Split(' ');
Console.WriteLine(split[split.Length - 2].Reverse());
```

The console should return "nemiceps"
The code seems right, but there's the wrong output.
Any tips?

Comment: `Reverse` is going to return a `IEnumerable<char>` you need to turn that back into a `string`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the linq [reverse](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.reverse) result to an [array](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.toarray) and pass it to the [string constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.string.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_String__ctor_System_Char___) like that:

```
string word = new string(split[split.Length - 2].Reverse().ToArray());

Console.WriteLine(word);
```

This convert the `IEnumerable<char>` to an array and create a new `string` from this array.